# Set up new head unit and back up camera goes on and off

Tags: honda, civic, backup-camera, head-unit

So I installed a new sony apple carplay head unit in my 2016 honda civic lx and set my backup. When I put the car in reverse the camera turns on. However, the camera tends to cut in and out and will turn off then turn back on while backing up. I have made sure the wires are not loose. I wired them using wire nuts and wonder if soldering these wires together would make the camera not go in and out. If anyone else would have any suggestions let me know. Thank you.

Comment: all you can do is solder them to see if it solves the issue.

Comment: I dont believe that is the issue. I might just have to connect directly to reverse lights rather than through the wiring harness

Comment: That is how I wire them and don't have issues, best bet.

Comment: Okay I will try when my friend comes home from vacation who has a soldering iron